# R Shiny layout - side by side chart and/or table within a tab

Tags: r, shiny

I wish to plot a curve and the data table side by side within a tab in R Shiny as shown in the images below. I am aware from the R Shiny layout documentation that the side by side plot and table layout is possible when not using tabs. But I would like to have the side by side layout within a tab if possible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can do it about the same way you would do it without tabs - within a tab you make different columns for your outputs. You can divide up the contents of each tab however you wish.

```
tabsetPanel(  
    tabPanel(h4("My Tab"),
      column(6,
         h3("My Plot"),
         plotOutput("My Plot")
       ),
       column(6,
         h3("My Table"),
         dataTableOutput("MyTable")
       )
      ),
     tabPanel(h4("Next Tab"),
       ..... etc
```